# How to connect outlook to OWA exchange servers?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have a OWA web app from work that I can access my email from a public website with MFA of course. It's not a cloud based mailbox on O365, but more of a OWA type mailbox.

I can connect to it from the mobile outlook app on a personal phone (not a work phone) and it shows as an exchange type mailbox. I can see calendar and get/send email.

But in windows 11, there is an outlook app that I would like to connect to this OWA. Problem is every type of connection I pick (outlook, imap, pop, exchange, legacy exchange, etc...), I can't seem to successfully connect.

Does anyone know how I can figure out the right connection settings?

Comment: Is this a work email address? If not, have you checked any instructions your host has provided? If so, you need to ask your IT people.

Comment: It is a work email, but I can access it using the android outlook app. So if I can access it from there, I'm thinking I should be able too from the outlook desktop app too?

Comment: Not necessarily. You need to ask your IT people about it. Because you're trying to connect a work service, you need to take this question to work people, not here. The method of connection is controlled by your employer and so our information may not be correct.

Comment: Outlook supports using the ActiveSync protocol to access mail accounts. Tried that yet?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that I'm not clear about your issue, and here are some questions I want to confirm to narrow down this issue.

1. OWA=outlook web App, this means that outlook on the web not one type of mailbox.
2. Does your mailbox host in exchange server?
3. What is the version of your outlook client in windows 11? For more details: [Windows 11 and Outlook; An easy upgrade?](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/windows11-upgrade.htm)
4. Is there any error messages when outlook connect to exchange server?
5. Run [EXRCA](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/Ola/input) to test outlook connectivity.